# QMake 'subdirs' template - executing a target?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am putting together a build system for my Qt app using a qmake .pro file that uses the 'subdirs' template.  This works fine, and allows me to specify the order that each target is built, so dependencies work nicely.  However, I have now added a tool to the project that generates a version number (containing the build date, SVN revision, etc,) that is used by the main app - I can build this version tool first but when it is built I want to execute it before any more targets are built (it generates a header file containing the version number that the main app includes.)

For example, my simple qmake file looks like something this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS = version \
          lib \
          tests \
          mainapp
```

When 'version' is built I want to execute it (passing some arguments on the command-line) before 'lib' is built.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I see that qmake has a 'system' command that can execute apps, but I don't know how I could leverage this.

A related question concerns my unit tests.  These live in the 'test' project and use the QTest framework.  I want to execute the tests exe before building 'mainapp' and if the tests fail (i.e. the tests exe doesn't return zero) I want to quit the build process.

I realise that qmake is designed to generate makefiles, so I may be wishing for a little too much here but if anyone can give me some pointers it would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a message on the Qt Interest mailing list about a 'pre build' step and it can be done using a combination of PRE_TARGETDEPS and QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS.  Here is the response:

> You can specify custom build steps,
>   eg. this would call makemyversion.sh
>   to  create myversion.cpp every time
>   before it builds something:
>
> ```
> versiontarget.target = myversion.cpp
> versiontarget.commands = ./makemyversion.sh
> versiontarget.depends = FORCE
>
> PRE_TARGETDEPS += myversion.cpp
> QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += versiontarget
> ```

I am now using something similar to this to generate my app's version number each time it is built.

Comment: pre build is tricky to find for qt, since they only have a built in QMAKE_POST_LINK, QMAKE_PRE_LINK and no QMAKE_PRE_BUILT. Thanks for sharing. +2

Answer (score 10):

I currently use qmake to exec my unit tests automatically for two years - and it works fine.

Have a look here - I made a mini-howto for that:

[Qt: Automated Unit Tests with QMAKE](http://www.3dh.de/?p=97)

## Abridged summary:

---

### Structure

```
/myproject/
    myproject.h
    myproject.cpp
    main.cpp
    myproject.pro
/myproject/tests/
    MyUnitTest.h
    MyUnitTest.cpp
    main.cpp
    tests.pro
```

### Using QMake to automatically run unit tests on build

The QMake target QMAKE_POST_LINK will run a user defined command after linking.

**tests.pri (common file)**

```
TEMPLATE = app
DEPENDPATH += . ../
INCLUDEPATH += . ../
DESTDIR = ./
CONFIG += qtestlib
unix:QMAKE_POST_LINK=./$$TARGET
win32:QMAKE_POST_LINK=$${TARGET}.exe
```

**tests.pro (project-specific file)**

```
TARGET = MyUnitTest
HEADERS += MyUnitTest.h
SOURCES += MyUnitTest.cpp main.cpp
include(tests.pri)
```

### Running multiple unit tests in a single main()

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyUnitTest1.h"
#include "MyUnitTest2.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    int retval(0);
    retval +=QTest::qExec(&MyTest1(), argc, argv);
    retval +=QTest::qExec(&MyTest2(), argc, argv);

    return (retval ? 1 : 0);
}
```

This runs your tests on each build and aborts if an error is found.

### Note

If you get linker errors such as "LNK2005: xxx already defined...", add a new .cpp file for each test class header and move some test method implementations.

---

You can use exactly that mechanism to exec your versioning tool after compile/building - so your questions should be solved :-)

If you have any further questions don't hesitate to ask me.

PS: Here you can find more (undocumented) tricks around QMake: [Undocumented QMake](http://wiki.qtcentre.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake)

Comment: Thanks.  I just read your blog post and I have another solution for multiple QTest's that means you don't need to edit main.cpp to add new tests - they are 'registered' automatically, similar to how the Boost auto test framework works.  Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: That sound really interestig - of course am I interested :)

greetz,
Chris

Comment: change `&MyTest1()` to `MyTest1 test; ... &test`

Comment: if a class in project inherits Q_OBJECT there will be `vtable error. is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do a lot of stuff with qmake as a build system over the years. Eventually I just resorted to having a pre-qmake step. Ie. a configure script.

You can build your version tool in there and then execute it before calling qmake to generate the Makefiles.

I found the easiest way to get data into the pro files, if you need that too, is to generate a .pro.inc file and include it from your main pro.

Answer (score 0):

As [3DH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167573/qmake-subdirs-template-executing-a-target/1168101#1168101) mentioned, you want a [`QMAKE_POST_LINK`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-post-link) option specified in your .pro files that contain something you want executed.  So for your example, I would do something like this with the `version.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = version
HEADERS = version.h
SOURCES = version.cpp
QMAKE_POST_LINK=./version
```

Something similar should work with your test directory.